# getting HTTP_REFERER in a landing page - brings back the landingpage url

Tags: php, http-referer

I have a landing page with a form in it. the form has a form action to a php file. I send all the fields that the client filled to a an api, like that:

```
$input_email = isset($_POST['email']) ? check_plain($_POST['email']) : 'None';
$input_name = isset($_POST['name']) ? check_plain($_POST['name']) : 'None';
$input_website = isset($_POST['website']) ? check_plain($_POST['website']) : 'None';
$input_website = strtolower($input_website);
$input_content = isset($_POST['content']) ? check_plain($_POST['content']) : 'None';
$previous = $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'];
```

As you can see in the last line, i get the HTTP_REFERER from the page. But doing this brings back the url of the landing page, and not the referral url for the landing page. (for example: if my landing page is example.com and the client got there from google.com i want $previous to have google.com, but instead i have example.com)

Is there any way to make it work?
Also note that I am aware of the problems with using HTTP_REFERER

Comment: you could add a hidden field and assign a session array to it (rather than relying on `HTTP_REFERER`), set to the current page/url

Comment: I know that. anyway, see the answer below. it's exactly what I meant yet using `HTTP_REFERER` which I wouldn't rely on. I know you said you're aware of it, but you really shouldn't use it. Edit: you deleted your comment now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So what's happening here is that your initial page load has the (assumed) correct http referer, but once the user posts the form, the referer becomes your own domain

In the form on the landing page you could do something along these lines

```
<?php if (isset($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'])): ?>
<input type="hidden" name="http_referer" value="<?= $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']; ?>" />
<?php endif; ?>
```

Then when you do your post processing you can check for the existence of

`$_POST['http_referer']`

and act accordingly